# Amazon ec2 or Google cloud separate billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, amazon-vpc, aws-systems-manager

I gave got a software which is installed on multiple ubuntu/ec2 machines.

I need the same setup for multiple clients. Each client should only be given option to

- pay the bill,
- scale the ec2 machines
- start the ec2 machine
- stop the ec2 machine

Each clients bill will be paid by the client themselves and I should not interfere. If unpaid his account should be terminated automatically and I cannot be held responsible.

Can this be achieved in aws or google cloud ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GCP for the payments you may give the users permissions of [Billing administrator](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access)

For the VM's you might create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles) with individual [Compute permissions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/)

(instance.start, instance.stop, instance.start, instance.setmachinetype, etc)